# LimeSurvey RemoteControl API failing in localhost in Macos Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, json-rpc, limesurvey

*Currently using Version 2.57.1+161205 of Lime Survey.*

I recently got a new Macbook Pro laptop and set up my dev environment. Everything seems to be working except when I try to make JSON RPC calls to the LimeSurvey Remotecontrol API!

It fails at getting the session key from Lime Survey (let alone any other call).
It just pauses for a bit then returns an error saying it is unable to connect to the server. Before the Mac, I had a Windows based PC using Vagrant/Homestead - I had no problems accessing the API.

If I open a browser tab and type in http://lime.app/admin/remotecontrol (lime.app is my vhost pointing to my limesurvey installation) -- I get the list of available API functions etc
But when I try to use the functions through the RPC client (I'm using weberhofer/jsonrpcphp), I get the error.

As a test, I tried to get a session key from an online instance of LimeSurvey (its in a test server). That works perfectly.
But when I'm trying to do the same call locally, it fails each time.
Is there something that needs to be set in the Mac to allow this type of call??

Answer (score 1):

I didn't work out if this was just a Mac issue, but I seem to have resolved the problem.

I'm using the JSON RPC client from https://github.com/weberhofer/jsonrpcphp 
On a whim I thought I'd try a different client, so I decided to use https://github.com/fguillot/JsonRPC instead.

Strange thing is, it works!! I have no idea why the previous client would no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a mac address issue , right?
I am not a mac user, so I can't help you much.

Nevertheless, I would test if you are pointing to the right server.
As that open the remotecontrol_handle file and add some kind of error_log command in the get_session_key function. That will tell if Lime is ever being contacted or not.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't worked out why it would suddenly stop working though. See my answer. On a whim I tested with a different package and it now works as expected.

Comment: Twilight Zone stuff..!!